# Insert marker symbol in figtext

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to reference the marker symbols as a part of a short text used for plots (such as scatter) in a figtext manually inserted figtext to provide additional context.
Background: I use color to indicate datasets and markers to differentiate different years for those datasets. In other words: Markers add an additional dimension to the plot.

Since there are a lot of datasets (12) and 6 different markers, I would like to avoid adding all of them to the legend. Instead, I want to place text with the marker symbols on the figure.

I have thus far failed to find a way to "Print" the marker symbol.

Can anyone help?

see above: tried to use:

```
import matplotlib.markers as mmark
[...]
plt.figtext(0,0, mmark.MarkerStyle('.'))
```

but that only prints "<matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle ..." into the figure.

Comment: In the documentation `MarkerStyle` is used in the context of `pyplot`'s `plot`, `scatter`, and  `errorbar`. It doesn't seem like it can be used with `figtext` (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html).

Comment: I feared as much - is there any other way to "print" the marker symbols?
I guess there is always making the entire legend from scratch...

Comment: unfortunately `print`ing or the like will just return the symbol's marker number as an integer.